# Deserialize JSON object with null arrays using newtonsoft.json

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I am hitting a web service that returns a JSON-like response, and I am trying to deserialize the response to C# objects.  I hused the Visual Studio Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes method to create the base version of the classes.  When I try to deserialize the web service response to those classes using the method below (where rawResp is the response from the web service as text)

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ApplyEditsResult>>(rawResp);
```

i get the following error message:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'Rid20Api.Models.ApplyEditsResult+Result' because the type
>   requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix
>   this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or
>   change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g.
>   not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array
>   or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object. Path '[0].addResults[0].objectId',
>   line 1, position 35.

I have tried adding "JsonObject" attribute to the appropriate classes; added the
JsonArray attribute as well. What am i missing to correctly deserialize the response?

The response from the web service:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "addResults": [
      {
        "objectId": 1215,
        "globalId": "{5a3d5c49-856c-4de4-9d20-c7abf0e070c8}",
        "success": true
      }
    ],
    "attachments": {
      "addResults": [],
      "deleteResults": [],
      "updateResults": []
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "addResults": [
      {
        "objectId": 819,
        "globalId": "{459f456a-c115-4f9c-b1f9-d754d55980dd}",
        "success": true
      },
      {
        "objectId": 820,
        "globalId": "{f690cded-2ffb-4301-ab6e-58ae9733eeba}",
        "success": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and the classes (it hasn't made any difference whether the classes are nested or are 'stand-alone'):

```
    public class ApplyEditsResult
    {

        public int id { get; set; }
        public Result[] addResults { get; set; }
        public Result[] updateResults { get; set; }
        public Result[] attachments { get; set; }

        [JsonObject]
        public class Attachments
        {
            [JsonProperty("addResults")]
            public object[] addResults { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("deleteResults")]
            public object[] deleteResults { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("updateResults")]
            public object[] updateResults { get; set; }
        }

        [JsonArray(AllowNullItems = true)]
        [JsonObject]
        public class Result
        {
            public bool success { get; set; }
            public Error error { get; set; }
            public int objectId { get; set; }
            public string globalId { get; set; }
        }

        [JsonObject]
        public class Error
        {
            public int code { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

**EDIT**.........
Here is the unedited collection of classes created by the VS tools. As noted above and in the comments below, i changed some of these classes 1) to better fit my code (including error responses from the service) and 2) in an (failed) attempt to correct the bug myself.

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Addresult[] addResults { get; set; }
    public Attachments attachments { get; set; }
}

public class Attachments
{
    public object[] addResults { get; set; }
    public object[] deleteResults { get; set; }
    public object[] updateResults { get; set; }
}

public class Addresult
{
    public int objectId { get; set; }
    public string globalId { get; set; }
    public bool success { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `[JsonArray(AllowNullItems = true)]` on top of `Result` class.

Comment: public Result[] addResults { get; set; } public Result[] updateResults { get; set; } public Result[] attachments { get; set; } the all object has same return type. It will not parse. Json schema should similar to Class hierarchy

Comment: VS did not make those classes - you are missing the RootObject which is supposed to hold an AddResult list, a Attachments object and an int

Comment: @Plutonix - I did use VS to create the classes. I dropped the 'RootObject' because the response from the web service didn't have a 'root' for the JSON (instead it just returns an array). My mistake was changing the name of the class 'AddResult' to 'Result'. in an attempt to use that class as a generic 'result' for adds, deletes, and updates. and that didn't go so well.

Comment: `ApplyEditsResult` ***is*** the Root Object.  None of the robot tools puts the related types as nested classes.

Comment: @Plutonix: i have edited the original post to include the original classes as generated by the VS tools. You are correct, the tool did not create the nested classes. As i inferred (probably could have been more clear), the nested classes were a (failed) attempt on my part to resolve the bug myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class should look like this

```
public class AddResult
{

    [JsonProperty("objectId")]
    public int objectId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("globalId")]
    public string globalId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public bool success { get; set; }
}

public class Attachments
{

    [JsonProperty("addResults")]
    public List<object> addResults { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("deleteResults")]
    public List<object> deleteResults { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("updateResults")]
    public List<object> updateResults { get; set; }
}

public class ApplyEditsResult
{

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("addResults")]
    public List<AddResult> addResults { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("attachments")]
    public Attachments attachments { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ApplyEditsResult>>(rawResp);
```